# Trying to extend a LabelFor MVC4 helper, and not being picked up... puzzled?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4, ASP.NET4.5, C#

I am trying to get my application to use my extended LabelFor helpers, but the original MS helpers seem to be used all of the time.

My calling code:

```
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.myRecords.First().myColumn)
```

My Helper:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
```

I have only added the start of the helper as I believe the issue is to do with the helper parameter signature. I am assuming if my calling signature matches my helper signature then the above helper will be used rather than the standard MS LabelFor code.

Any advice please?
Thanks.

EDIT

Altered to "myColumn" where "myColumn" would have a "displayname" which might contain a "$" which I may want to replace in my extension of "LabelFor".

Comment: What do you want the helper to do? If you have the same signature, then change the name of the method (say `MyLabelFor(....)`)

Comment: I was wanting to access the labeltext and substitute some chars ie Currency. Currently the displayname are pulled from the entity model. Also if I kept the same "LabelFor" name then I would not need to change all of the LabelFors throughout the app to do this. There are loads, hence why I want to intercept the "LabelFor" code and add some extra processing code.

Comment: I have added an EDIT to clarify. Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: Then you need to give it a different signature (say with an additional parameter - but you still going to have to change all the html to use the new signature)

Comment: Thanks for this. So you cannot do some form of "override" with the same signature as the MS "LabelFor" helper?

Comment: Incidentally I have got a different signature helper working fine. However this does mean I will have to go through the app and change all the calls, where relevant, to use this new extended signature

Comment: And your edit does not make sense. The `LabelFor()` method displays the name of the property (or the value of the `DisplayAttribute` if present) and a property name cannot contain a `$` character, so I assume your using a `DisplayName` attribute, so why not just change its `Name` property?

Comment: Yes I am working with "DisplayName". I still need to intercept this in an extended helper, which as I understand it, will only work if I create a different signature to that of the standard MS "LabelFor" methods. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish? Just change the `Name` property (or use a resource file if you want different values based on cultures etc)

Comment: The new value is a "Currency Symbol", and it can be different for each user. So the DisplayName might originally be Cost ($), and then in the LabelFor I was wanting to intercept this and change it to Cost (£) for example.

Comment: Which suggests you want to change it based on the user culture (i.e. if its `en-GB` the display one symbol and if its `en-US` display another) so you should be using resource files.

Comment: No the user can change it for different reports, so it is a user setting in the DB which needs picking up by the intercepting LabelFor helper. I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: That suggest your accessing the database in the extension method - that awful practice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104934/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-samjolly).

Comment: Actually I am not doing it directly there, but via the newing of a model class. The point is that the value is dynamic, and that is why I am wanting to replace in an extension helper. I wondering whether I have taken enough of your time.